# Select id from input list NOT present in database

Tags: mysql, sql, select

With MySql vers 8.0:

```
CREATE TABLE cnacs(cid VARCHAR(20), PRIMARY KEY(cid));
```

Then,

```
INSERT INTO cnacs VALUES('1');
```

The first two statements execute successfully. The next statement does not, however. My goal is to return a list of unused cid's from the input table [1, 2]:

```
SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('1'),('2')) as T(cid) EXCEPT SELECT cid FROM cnacs;
```

In theory, I'd like the output to be '2', since it has not yet been added. The aforementioned query was inspired by Remus's answer on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37627/identifying-which-values-do-not-match-a-table-row

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Not all products have the following feature outside SQL-2016:
F641, Row and table constructors, 
F591, Derived tables and
F661, Simple tables.

Comment: MySQL does not support `VALUES()` with that syntax.

Comment: For reference, I'm using: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d507b11f53fbce5c2dc78f254d2b2205

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is at least the correct syntax for what you are trying to do.

If this query is anything more than a learning exercise though I'd rethink the approach, storing these '1' and '2' values (or however many there ends up being) in their own table

```
SELECT Column_0
  FROM (SELECT * FROM (VALUES ROW('1'), ROW('2')) TMP) VALS
  LEFT
  JOIN cnacs
    ON VALS.Column_0 = cnacs.cid
 WHERE cnacs.cid IS NULL
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. In this specific case, I need only one unique ID, so I just append LIMIT 1 to your query and get 1 row in return

Comment: I was under the beginner illusion that all SQL languages were mostly syntactically unified

Comment: @ThomasBraun There is a lot of commonality, all major DBMS product support the ansi standard but beyond that each has their own particulars. For whatever reason MySql does have more particulars than most though.

Comment: Is there a good service for converting between sql languages? I'd like the query in pgsql, sqlite, and mssql

Comment: @ThomasBraun There may be tools that claim to do that, but in my experience tools that make claims like that rarely live up to the sales pitch. Your best bet, if portability is important, is sticking as close to the ansi standard as possible, and only using platform specific sql when it provides a significant simplification. For example, window functions are not supported on earlier MySql versions, but they can really simplify queries. You can use a tool like http://sqlfiddle.com/ though to check whether a given query/syntax is runnable on each of those platforms.